# The zero component of tensor products of graded mods

Tags: reference-request, graded-modules

I guarantee there is an easy reference on this, but for some reason I cannot find it. If you can point me to a reference or just write a short proof for me, I would be very appreciative.

Given a graded ring $R_{\bullet}$ and a localization $R_{\bullet}^{*}$. We also have a graded $R_{\bullet}$-mod, $M_{\bullet}$.

So what I want to know; is $\left(R_{\bullet}^{*}\otimes M_{\bullet}\right)_0=\left(R_{\bullet}^{*}\right)_0\otimes \left(M_{\bullet}\right)_0$?

Comment: I cant get the dumb tex to work...

Comment: Wrap the whole formula in backticks \` (including the dollar signs)

Comment: @Mariano You must be some kind of sorcerer...

Comment: By the way, the bullet does not help much in the notation :)

Comment: Oops that was a typo, it should not be a module over the localization

Comment: Suppose $R=k[t]$ with its usual grading, and $M=R(1)$ is free of rank one generated in degree $1$.

Comment: Thank you, I guess there wont be a reference... I suppose you should post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a counterexample, take $R=k[t]$ with its usual grading and $M=R(1)$, the free module of rank one generated in degree $1$.